# Prevent Apps from Hiding Navigation Bar

Tags: cyanogenmod, screen, buttons, home-button

I am using CyanogenMod 12 (Lollipop) and I have Expanded Desktop disabled for all apps.

However, there are some apps that either "minimize" my Navigation Bar, turning the buttons into small dots and I have to touch them to enable again. An example is CameraZOOM (slide.cameraZoom).

[image]

There are also other apps that hide the Navigation Bar completely, usually putting some Ad behind it. An example is Jelly Jump (com.ketchapp.jellyjump).

Is there any way I can disable this functionality, and make my Navigation Bar completely unchangeable? This is very annoying and I think apps shouldn't have any control on these buttons in any way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm using to control this behavior is App Settings Xposed module. If you've never used Xposed before, it's fairly easy to install, you just flash a zip, install an app, and you're ready to go.

App Settings enables you to control the immersive behaviour of your app, on per-app basis.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll definitely try it. I do have Xposed installed, actually, but I never enabled it since I don't know it it will be compatible with CyanogenMod. Have you ever experienced any problems with CyanogenMod + Xposed? Regards.

Comment: @Nuno , no, I've never experienced any problems with it, it worked as expected and never caused instability to the system.

Comment: Hey! I've just made sure Xposed is working and installed the App Settings module. I went to CameraZOOM options and set "Full Screen" to "Prevent" (there's the Immersive option there as well). It doesn't seem to stop the navigation bar from minimizing the buttons (turn them into dots). Any ideas here? :) but there are many interesting stuff here, though! Thank you very much.